# Equivalence of Definitions of a Disconnection

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, connectedness

In our calculus class we are given the following definition for a disconnection. We say that a disconnection for $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a pair $\{U,V\}$ of open subsets s.t

- $U \cap S$ and $V \cap S$ are non-empty
- $(U \cap S) \cup (V \cap S) = S$
- $(U \cap S) \cap (V \cap S) = \emptyset$

It then says that $U \cap V = \emptyset$ is not required. If we replace the last condition with $U \cap V = \emptyset$, do we have an equivalent definition of a disconnection? Or is there some set that is disconnected by the definition above, but every such $U,V$ has $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: If you had $U∩ V ≠ \{ \}$ then the third condition implies that $U∩ V  = U∩ V ∩ S^c$ so just delete $U∩ V $ from both $U$ and $V$ to create $U'$ and $V'$ that also satisfy the 'stronger' $U'∩ V' = \{\}$. I imagine you just don't need to use this property in your class, even if the picture is nicer in your head.

Answer (score 0):

This a little bit confusing question, because $ S $ doesn't have to be open.

If $ S $ is open, then I believe you know the answer.

Now, before I'll exaplain you about the second case, I'll remind where this definition come from.

If you have a topology $ X $, and you take $ S \subset X $ (in your case: $ X = \mathbb{R}^n $). Then you can define the **induced topology** which will be a topology which its elements will be of the form $ O \cap S $ where $ O $ is open in $ X $. Those elements doesn't need to be open in $ X $!

Now, you define a topology $ X $ to be **connected** if there are two disjoint open sets $ O_1,O_2 $ such that $ O_1 \cup O_2 = X $.

Now, you can varify that your definition of open subset only demands the induced topology of the set to be connected.

So, if you're looking for sets $ S $ and open sets $ U,V $ that satistify your condition, then you need to take a non-open set $ S $. Think about it copule of minutes and then continue.

> 

One example of it is a line without a dot (Prove!). Try to find another exmaples.